# Partition on hard drive unmountable, unable to recover data

Tags: external-hard-drive, partition-recovery, file-recovery

The hard drive in question used to be hooked up to my Raspberry Pi 3, formatted with NTFS and used as a small file server. I have recently dug up the hard drive again to pull the data from it, but after numerous attempts, I have failed to access it through multiple means.

I have tried accessing it through the Pi it used to be hooked up to, but trying to mount it or even get details about the drive result in no data being shown at all, and usually ended in me having to restart the SSH session completely due to the session completely locking up. I tried using `fdisk -l` to see if it would show the disk which it didn't, however running `lsblk` showed the disk. I then tried
using smartmontools to get info on the drive, but it showed screen with no information, and I again had to kill the SSH session to be able to back out of the screen.

I tried using software like Disk Drill and the EaseUS recovery software on Windows to see if they can find the files, which they can, but I don't have the money to spend on a license key to recover the data. With that knowledge though, I tried to use diskpart to try and manually attach a drive letter to the partition (which does shows up in diskmgmt, but the only option it gives me is to delete the volume), but when running `detail disk`, it reports that there are no volumes present. When I run `list part` however, the partition shows up and I can select it, but when trying to run `attributes volume`, it then reports that there is no volume selected.

I am honestly at a loss, so I am asking this question here to see if anyone has an idea that I haven't been able to think of or find through research.

Comment: Have you tried a data recovery tool like [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)? This has helped me recover data from a damaged SSD in a similar situation. Btw, why are you using NTFS on a Linux system? A Linux-native file system like ext4 would probably more reliable.

Comment: _Do not work directly on the disk_. You don't want to accidentally overwrite something important. Make a sector-by-sector copy to a 2nd disk and work on it.

Comment: @gronostaj Will do, sounds like the sensible way to go about it moving forward...

Comment: @StarCat I have never heard of this tool before, thanks for pointing it out! I formatted it in NTFS at the time because I used it as a network drive in Windows. It was a little convoluted... but it worked well.

Comment: In case you want to create such setup again in the future, the filesystem doesn't matter for network drives and ext4 would work just fine. The filesystem itself isn't exposed through the network, so clients don't need to support it - just the server.